# Twice differentiable implies equality of mixed partials?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I have seen the following theorem claimed in several places:

**Claim:** If a function $f$ of two variables has partial derivatives $f_x$ and $f_y$ which are defined in a neighborhood of $(a,b)$ and are also differentiable at $(a,b)$, then the mixed partials are equal: $f_{xy}= f_{yx}$.

This is a stronger claim than what I find in most textbooks and also on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_partial_derivatives#Schwarz.27_theorem), which also assumes that the second partial derivatives are continuous.

If the above claim is true, where can I find a proof of it?  And if not, what is a counterexample?  (The latter is basically [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716690/a-function-with-differentiable-partial-derivatives-but-unequal-mixed-derivatives).)

It is stated on page 201 or 220 (maybe depending on edition) of *Advanced Calculus* by Angus Taylor, but no proof is given.

I have also found it in a 1908 paper called *On Differentials* by W. H. Young in Proc. LMS, but I don't believe the proof given.  He uses differentiability of $f_x$ to show that

$$ \frac{f_x(x+h,y+k) - f_x(x+h,y)}{k} = \frac{h}{k}e + f_{yx} + e' $$

where $e,e'\to 0$ as $(h,k)\to 0$, and therefore that the LHS goes to $f_{yx}$ as $(h,k)\to 0$ "provided $h/k$ does not become infinite".  Similarly, $\frac{f_y(x+h,y+k) - f_y(x,y+k)}{h} \to f_{xy}$ as $(h,k)\to 0$ "provided $k/h$ does not become infinite".  Then he roughly follows the usual proof of equality of mixed partials, using the mean value theorem to show that

$$ \frac{f(x+h,y+k)-f(x+h,y) - f(x,y+k) + f(x,y)}{hk} = \frac{f_y(x+h,y+\theta k) - f_y(x,y+\theta k)}{h} $$

for some $0<\theta<1$, and dually.  Then he says "if $(h,k)$ moves towards $(0,0)$ in such a way that $h/k$ has not zero as limit, $h/\theta k$ will not have zero for a limit", so that the RHS above goes to $f_{xy}$, and dually also to $f_{yx}$.  But it seems to me that $\theta$ depends on $h$ and $k$, so there is no reason it might not blow up as $(h,k)\to 0$ even if $h/k$ has a finite nonzero limit.  Is there some reason why this works?

Comment: Have you checked $f(x,y) = \frac{(x^2 - y^2)^2}{x^2 + y^2}$?  I thought this was a counter-example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The result is correct. Note that they are *not* saying just that the second partial derivatives exist. They are saying that the derivative map
$$Df(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) & \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)\end{bmatrix}$$
is *differentiable* as a function $U\to L(\Bbb R^2,\Bbb R)$, where $U$ is a neighborhood of $(a,b)$ and $L(E,F)$ denotes the vector space of linear maps from $E$ to $F$.

This implies that the second derivative gives you a symmetric bilinear map $\Bbb R^2\times\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$, i.e., that the mixed partials are equal.

This is proved, for example, in Dieudonné's multi-volume Analysis text.

Comment: @MikeShulman: I'm most likely retiring to San Diego in a year or so. You guys need an adjunct who's a geometer? :)